# Concept Based Polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, duck-typing

I have been reading up on Concept based Inheritance in C++. I have a attached a code sample for all. I am basically asking if this is a correct implementation of the concept of this? I am new to this so I am just putting down what is in my mind. Any comments / critisims are welcome.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

class graphics_surface{

    class drawable_concept{
    public:
        virtual void draw(Point const& coordinate) {};
        virtual ~drawable_concept() {};
    };

    template<class T>
    class drawable_model : public drawable_concept{
    public:
        drawable_model(T& item) : item_(item){}
        void draw(Point const& coordinate){
            item_.draw(coordinate);
        }
        ~drawable_model(){}
    private:
        T item_;
    };

public:

    template<class T>
    void push_back(T& drawable){
        v_.push_back(shared_ptr<drawable_concept>( new drawable_model<T>(drawable)));
    }

    void draw(Point const& coordinate) {
        for_each(v_.begin(), v_.end(), [&](shared_ptr<drawable_concept>& concept){
            concept->draw(coordinate);
        });
    }

private:
    vector<shared_ptr<drawable_concept>> v_;
};

struct triangle{
    void draw(Point const& p){
        cout << "Triangle: " << p.x << "," << p.y << endl;
    }
};

struct square{
    void draw(Point const& p){
        cout << "Sqaure: " << p.x << "," << p.y << endl;
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Point p;
    p.x = 1;
    p.y = 2;

    graphics_surface surface;
    surface.push_back(triangle());

    surface.draw(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Blair

Comment: I don't see anything about concepts in there. It's just normal class-based polymorphism (whatever the proper name for that is). (edit: oh, now I see how this works... this comment might be completely wrong)

Comment: Note: "Concepts" is strongly associated by C++ programmers with the C++0x proposal for checking that types passed as template parameters supported specific semantics; this question is about "Concept Based Polymorphism" which is a distinct idiom for using compile-time polymorphism to create a run-time polymorphic object.

Comment: Yep this is what I am talking about Tony D. Keen for comments.

Comment: The tag "c++-concepts" is supposed to be about the c++0x/y proposed language feature.

Comment: Updated the example with a gist at https://gist.github.com/loosechainsaw/9049615

Comment: This question is specifically talking about Sean Parent's work: [Concept-based Runtime Polymorphism](http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/images/c/c9/Boost_poly.pdf).

Comment: `drawable_concept::draw` should be a pure virtual function; the concept class is never supposed to be instantiated and that can be enforced by making it abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- I don't see any good reason to put `drawable_concept` or `drawable_model` inside `graphics_surface` - you just prevent reuse of something that's potentially useful in other container types...
- you have some `const` issues

  - `draw` should probably be `const` (and function definitions should not be followed by semicolons ;-)
  - `drawable_model(T& item)` should take `item` by `const` reference
  - `push_back(T& drawable)` shoudl take `drawable` by `const` reference
- you should use `make_shared` for exception safety
- the "factory" functionality would arguably be better off separated into a separate function, rather than buried inside `push_back`

Comment: Good points. Do you think this is a reasonable implementation of Concept Based Polymorphism?

Comment: @BlairDavidson: the basic functionality is there... the rest comes down to suiting your actual use(s) and should come out in the wash.  There are noteworthy variations - for example, creating run-time polymorphic objects wrapping just a pointer to the concrete type, rather than having the concrete object owned by the wrapper and *necessarily* heap allocated.  Which is optimal depends on the relative lifetimes, whether you're trying to minimise data copying (e.g. concurrent runtime polymorphic access to objects in shared-memory works with the pointer/wrapper).

Comment: This question is specifically talking about Sean Parent's work: [Concept-based Runtime Polymorphism](http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/images/c/c9/Boost_poly.pdf). The example uses private concept and model classes, though it doesn't explicitly cover the motivation for that choice.

Comment: @bames53: I'm confused by your assertion, though not taking issue with it.  Do you know / are you Blair - to know what *"specifically"* the question's talking about?  Or are you saying they're an exact match, and/or that nobody else has published anything similar so it's the only candidate for Blair's *"I have been reading up"*?

Comment: @TonyD There's no other candidate, and Blair's code matches the example code given in the linked presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach here is more about type erasure than it is about Concept based programming. It's an extension of the idea used by boost::any. Concepts are a set of constraints on a type required by a class or function template. The STL has concepts such as ForwardIterator and InputIterator. These are constraints that are expected to be true for parameters passed to some std algorithms for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, "Concepts" per your answer and the deferred/killed(?) C++0x proposal are a completely different thing from what some people have been calling "Concept Based Polymorphism" - templated factories for capturing specific operations on arbitrary types - which is what the question is about.

Comment: Hmm. Yes I agree with your assessment of my answer.